# Java-AngularJS http get method gets the string with "" and escape characters

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, spring-mvc

I use this function to make a http get request:

```
    $scope.fetchResult = function() {
    $http.get('search/result').success(function(getResult){
        $scope.result = getResult;
    });
};
```

This is the backend function:

```
    @RequestMapping("/result")
public @ResponseBody String getResult() {
    return searchService.getResult();
}
```

Problem is it prints the string to web page with " character at the beginning and at the end also escape characters too. I cannot really find any logic behind this. For instance if string is:

```
String result = "Hello";
```

It doesn't print Hello to the web page but it prints "Hello" instead. Another example:

```
String result = "Found \"" + keyword + "\" '" + count + "' times at \"" + website + "\"";
```

It prints escape characters too. So let's say keyword is keyword, count is 0 and web site is http://stackoverflow.com result is printed this way on the web page:

```
"Found \""keyword"\" '"0"' times at \""http://stackoverflow.com"\""
```

While obviously I expect:

```
Found "keyword" '0' times at "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

How can I fix this? This doesn't really make any sense to me I'm new to js and web development.

**Edit:** If I use `List<String>` instead of `String` and do this on html form:

```
<p ng-repeat:"res in result">{{res}}<p>
```

It works. But I don't really want to use it this way since I don't need list but a single String.

Comment: Do you mean Javascript or Java?

Comment: I mean java. I use java on backend and angularjs on frontend.

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Spring from a search for `RequestMapping`, and if that's the case you'll probably need to change the options to spit out a format you want. I suggest a JSON response instead of a naked string, or create an AngularJS $http interceptor to transform the data before getting to the callback.  FYI, `success` and `error` are now fully deprecated and removed as of 1.6.

Comment: @Phix tried returning JsonObject too but it also didn't work. Prashant I print it on html page using {{result}}. That's how AngularJS works it's not related to the problem.

Comment: This appears to be more of a Spring issue than an AngularJS one then.

Comment: how to build   String  in  searchService.getResult() method update sample logic what you write in getResult()

Answer (score 0):

Spring has something called Suffix Strategy which enables the framework to check for a path extension right from the URL to determine the output content type.

The encoded result you see happens because the result is returned as a Json object due to the `@RequestMapping` being set as `/result.json` with a `.json` extension.

To resolve this issue you have multiple options.

## Option 1:

Handle the returned response as a Json object in your Javascript.

## Option 2:

rename the `@RequestMapping` value to be just `/result`. Below is a code example:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
   @RequestMapping(value="/result")
   public @ResponseBody String sayHello() {
      String website = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      int count = 4;
      String keyword = "keyword";
      return "Found \"" + keyword + "\" '" + count + "' times at \"" + website + "\"";
   }
}
```

Javascript (Adding accept header is optional here)

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/result",{headers: { 'Accept': 'text/plain' }})
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.result = response.data;
  });
});
</script>
```

## Option 3

Keep the `@RequestMapping` value as it as `/result.json` but disable the Suffix Strategy using a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Below is a code example

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
   @RequestMapping(value="/result.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
   public @ResponseBody String sayHello() {
      String website = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      int count = 4;
      String keyword = "keyword";
      return "Found \"" + keyword + "\" '" + count + "' times at \"" + website + "\"";
   }
}
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false)
        .favorParameter(false)
        .ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
        .useJaf(false)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/result.json",{headers: { 'Accept': 'text/plain' }})
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.result = response.data;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't angularjs's `$http.get` automatically parse content as JSON if the content type is set to `application/json`?

Comment: When I use it as you say it doesn't get anything.